# How to parse xml recived as response text?

Tags: javascript, web-services, xml-parsing

I am calling a webservice which is returning the xml data in encrypted format. I am receiving this as encrypted data as responseText. Now I want to parse this XML data. can you help me out

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are having the specific problem as it will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: $(respon).find('NewDataSet').find('Table').each(function(){
     
    x = $(this).find('line').text();
           y = $(this).find('Trimestre').text();
     
        });

 alert(x);
 i need to store in x value but its giving undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DomParser](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml%5fparser.asp) which allows you to parse xml.

```
if (window.DOMParser)
{
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(txt); 
}
```

then

```
var tag = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TagName");
```

However, before doing so, you will need to decrypt your response as you state in your question that the response is encrypted.